# Building an array of matrices

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, gfortran

I would like to split a large matrix into smaller 2 by 2 matrices and put them into an array. Here is what I tried.

```
PROGRAM flippableList

  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL, DIMENSION(4,4) :: TEST
  REAL, DIMENSION(2,2) :: su1
  REAL, DIMENSION(:,:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: breakdown

  REAL :: a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2
  INTEGER :: n, i, j

  a1 = 11; a2 = 12
  b1 = 21; b2 = 22
  c1 = 31; c2 = 32

  su1 = RESHAPE ([b1, c2, a2, b2],[2,2])
  TEST = RESHAPE ([c2, a2, a2, a2, a1, c2, a2, a2, &
      a1, a1, c2, a2, a1, a1, a1, c2], [4,4])
  n = 4 ! size of the grid

  ALLOCATE (breakdown(:,:,:))
  breakdown = 0
  DO i = 1, n-1, 1
    DO j = 1, n-1, 1
    breakdown = [breakdown, TEST(i:i+1, j:j+1)]
    END DO
  END DO

PRINT*, breakdown
END PROGRAM flippableList
```

From the error messages compiling with gfortran, I can tell there is a problem with `breakdown` dimension. Here are error messages.

ALLOCATE (breakdown(:,:,:))
            1
Error: Bad array specification in ALLOCATE statement at (1)
flippableList.f08:28:4:

```
 breakdown = [breakdown, TEST(i:i+1, j:j+1)]
1
```

Error: Incompatible ranks 3 and 1 in assignment at (1)

Comment: What are the error messages?  Also, note that `REAL, DIMENSION(:,2,2), ALLOCATABLE :: breakdown` is not a valid declaration: you must use `:`s instead of the `2`s.

Comment: And `ALLOCATE (breakdown(:,2,2))` is the same . The `:` can't be there. If you have any error messages, you MUST show them.

Comment: Given that TEST is a 4x4 matrix, how big should the first dimension of breakdown be? You need to specify this yourself in the `allocate` statement.

Comment: I replaced '2's with ':'s as advised by francescalus and Vladimir F and also added error messages. I also tried specifying the first dimension of breakdown but I got similar errors as above. The first dimension should be (n-1)^2 where n is the number of rows in matrix.

Comment: It seems like you're still struggling with how `allocate` works. Your declaration (`real, ...`) is correct, but you need to specify the exact dimensions when you call `allocate(`. There are many resources online about how this works.

Comment: Also, the `breakdown = [breakdown, TEST(i:i+1, j:j+1)]` statement will not work. For simplicity, I recommend specifying each individual element of breakdown independently.

Comment: Now it is working. I specified the size of the 'breakdown' as well as its elements independently. Thank you all who commented!